# VisualForce Page Set URL Parameter w/ Javascript

Tags: visualforce, javascript

I have a custom search VisualForce page. I have an inputText area for a search term, upon hitting enter I wan't to pass that value to URL parameter. Trying to do it via JavaScript.

I want URL to be apex/pageName?s=ValueEnteredInSearchBox

This is what I have right now which isn't working.

```
<body id="bodyPortalCaseSearch">
    <apex:form id="frmPortalCaseSearch">
        <apex:pageBlock id="pbPortalCaseSearch">
            <div class="table">
                <div class="tableRow">
                    <div id="searchDiv" class="tableCell">
                        <apex:inputText id="searchinput" style="width:85%; height:25px;margin:0; padding: 0px 6px 0px;"
                        title="Portal_Search_Phrase" value="{!portalSearchModel.searchTerm}" onkeypress="insertSearchParam()"
                        />
                        <apex:commandLink id="goSearch" title="Search" style="text-decoration:none;"
                        rerender="asQuestions,asAnswers,asSolutions,asIdeas,asCases,asContent">Search</apex:commandLink>
                        <script type="text/javascript">
                            function insertSearchParam() {
                                var val = document.getElementById("{!$Component.searchinput}").value;
                                document.location.search = "?s=" + val;
                                searches();
                            }
                            document.getElementById("{!$Component.searchinput}").onkeypress = function (e) {
                                if (!e) e = window.event; // resolve event instance
                                if (e.keyCode == '13') {
                                    insertSearchParam();
                                    return false;
                                }
                            }
                        </script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Best bet is a `form` using `GET` method.

```
<apex:page>
  <form method="GET">
    <input name="s" value="ValueEnteredInSearchBox" type="text" />
    <input type="submit" />
  </form>
</apex:page>
```

[image]